# Hiding wsdl's xml information in web browser on WCF?

Tags: xml, wcf, service, wsdl, asmx

Is there a way to let the clients use the wsdl, however only hide its xml which shows methods when opened in a web browser.

For example, following works very well for asmx:

```
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <wsdlHelpGenerator href="Blank.aspx"/>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
```

Is there any alternative of the above for svc?

Removing serviceMetadata or changing httpGetEnabled to false makes wsdl unusable, which is not what I want. I just want to make its contents invisible when opened in a web browser.

Comment: I think you can user `rewrite` and redirect user to another address.

Answer (score 0):

if you want redirect user to another address if he/she request your `svc` file you can use `rewrite` like:

```
<system.webServer> 
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <clear />
                  <rule name="Redirect to Blank" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^(.+wsdl.+)/?$" /> 
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://yourDomain/Blank.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

that should redirect user to `yourDomain/Blank.aspx` if the `wsdl` requested
but there should be another ways, but I have tested it on my system it works nice.

just add this configuration in config file of your services (Server-Side).

**UPDATE:**

you can also use `<match url="\b(wsdl|singleWsdl|svc)\b" />` to redirect URL which contains `svc` or `wsdl` or `singleWsdl`.

Comment: Any feedback? is this do what you want ?

Comment: Aria, sorry I am using this forum for the first time. I tried to comment on your answer but ended up adding it as an answer instead. Please take a look at that.

Comment: @saaz See the update, read some about Regex and URL Rewrite module, I think this answer give you nice solution with some changes as your expect.

Comment: Redirect worked fine now, however the original problem is back. I am no longer able to connect to the wsdl using SoapUI.

Comment: Yes of course it is not able because there is no difference between browse service in browser and SoapUI, I thought you are using that service in back-end code.

Comment: As I had written in my first post, this could simply be achieved by removing serviceMetadata from the config. But the problem is that I still want the clients to be able to connect using wsdl as they are already using it. So I wanted a way to just hide the xml in web browser without bothering those clients. I had in the past achieved it with wsdlHelpGenerator for asmx but don't know if similar thing can be done for wcf svc also

Comment: So tell me can I say I don't want this while I want use it ? if you want to use it you must have it, the best way is adding `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />` for service behavior to disable `wsdl`, I think you are misunderstanding .

Comment: I've also mentioned setting httpGetEnabled to false in my first post. So long story short, there is no way to achieve what I hoped for. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right direction, however that particular regex and action are not working exactly as I want

1) http://{domain}/{service}.svc -> https://{domain}/blank.aspx (good)

2) http://{domain}/{service}.svc?wsdl -> (shows an error when i press F12 as it is unable to find the blank.html page)

3) http://{domain}/{service}.svc?singleWsdl -> (does not change)

4) https://{domain}/{service}.svc -> (does not change)

5) https://{domain}/{service}.svc?wsdl -> (does not change)

6) https://{domain}/{service}.svc?singleWsdl -> (does not change)